# How to get manually pre-splitted region number used while creating table in hbase?

Tags: hadoop, split, hbase, hbase-shell

I am looking into a table with 126 regions right now through hbase shell. But I am unable to find out that how much region was manually defined during time of table creation. Is there any query I can execute and get that detail?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if I got what you want, but probably you can use the region time creation for this purpose. In your hdfs file system the hbase data is been stored in following format:

```
hbase
   /<Table>             (Tables in the cluster)
        /<Region>           (Regions for the table)
             /<ColumnFamiy>      (ColumnFamilies for the Region for the table)
                  /<StoreFile>        (StoreFiles for the ColumnFamily for the Regions for the table)
```

So you can use hdfs dfs -ls command to get the list of all the regions in your table. You can compare create dates of the regions to find out the history and probably the number of regions, set at the creation of the table:

```
hdfs dfs -ls /hbase/database/tablename/

drwxr-xr-x   - hbase hdfs          0 2016-07-27 12:36 /hbase/database/tablename/9d7c14813bfd871ccb10cf60d972787c
drwxr-xr-x   - hbase hdfs          0 2016-07-29 11:47 /hbase/database/tablename/f1cf0c45568153f35a03a183b6a096fa
```

Besides you can try accessing the metadata namespace of hbase via shell to get some info about your tables, but it would give you timestamps, what, for me personally, is more complicated option for your case compare to pure dates:

```
scan 'hbase:meta',{COLUMNS=> 'info:regioninfo', FILTER=>"PrefixFilter('yourtable')"}
```

Comment: Thank you alex I am going to try above, but don't we have a direct way to find out through command/query?

Comment: @Aamir You can probably try to get it from metadate, but it will return you a timespan, which could vary even for every region and as for me it is more easer to work with pure dates. I updated my answer with the option how to do this